# Accessing square bracket in Emacs with German Keyboard on Macbook with OS X

Tags: osx, keyboard-layout

With the Germany keyboard layout you need to press `ALT` aka `M` to reach certain character one needs for programming C,C++, Java, JS, etc. For instance to reach square brackets `[`, `]` you need to press `M-5` or `M-6`. But when I press `alt-5` (`M-5`) on my Apple Powerbook keyboard my Emacs/Spacemacs responds: `No window numbered 5.`

What would be a good way to either remap another key like `fn` as Meta-key or change the keyboard layout on my Macbook Pro for some characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have run into this issue before - also trying to use Emacs on OS X with a German keyboard for (C/C++) programming. My solution to this issue was to use the Command key as Meta and pass Option through to the OS to be able to pick up the special characters.

I use the following commands:

`(setq mac-command-modifier 'meta
      mac-option-modifier 'none
      default-input-method "MacOSX")`

I've blogged about this, and you can find the blog post that's a little more in depth over [here](https://www.lonecpluspluscoder.com/2014/01/22/make-gnu-emacs-play-nicely-with-a-german-keyboard-layout-on-mac-os-x/).

Comment: I successfully verified your solution, after I found a more detailed description and a different implementation of the same solution at the [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MetaKeyProblems).
The suggested solution there looks like this:

`;; Best option in Emacs 23 is to revert to Emacs 22 settings (alt is alt, cmd is meta) with this snippet:
    (setq mac-option-key-is-meta nil)
    (setq mac-command-key-is-meta t)
    (setq mac-command-modifier 'meta)
    (setq mac-option-modifier nil)`

Answer (score 2):

To change the meta key you can look at the variables `ns-command-modifier`, `ns-option-modifier`, `ns-control-modifier`, `ns-right-command-modifier`, `ns-right-option-modifier`, `ns-right-control-modifier`. On some versions of Emacs these will be `mac-` instead of `ns-`.

I have mine set up so that the left alt key is emacs meta and the right alt key generates the mac native keys — try setting `ns-right-option-modifier` to either `'none` or `nil`.

The other thing you can try is use `key-translation-map`:

```
(define-key key-translation-map [(meta ?5)] [?\[])
(define-key key-translation-map [(meta ?6)] [?\]])
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a related situation on my Windows 10 computer using Emacs 26.1, and a Norwegian keyboard layout. I'm used to using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and one of the number keys to access brackets, but it didn't work in Emacs (it ended up mass-adding characters instead).

[amitp](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/32831/19667)'s answer got me started, and I ended up adding this to the `.emacs` file:

```
(define-key key-translation-map [(control meta ?7)] [?\{])
(define-key key-translation-map [(control meta ?8)] [?\[])
(define-key key-translation-map [(control meta ?9)] [?\]])
(define-key key-translation-map [(control meta ?0)] [?\}])
```

On my keyboard, brackets are located on 7-0 using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>. <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> for brackets works out of the box, but it's (in my opinion) harder to type than using CTRL+Alt. For other keyboard layouts (i.e. German), it's enough just replacing the number with the appropriate number corresponding to the key used for brackets. It's also possible to remove either `control` or `meta` to just use one of the keys.

This should work on Mac and Linux as well, though I can't confirm if it works on a Mac because I don't have one.