# ALT as my modifier key stops me using a pound sign

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, evil, keyboard-layout

I've just switched to Spacemacs (Evil mode), as it is time to change things up, having used Sublime Text for years.

I have a British Mac keyboard which relies on ALT + 3 to output the pound sign (#).

If I want to run `:#,#s/` then I get a message saying *no window 3*, so I need to fix my key bindings and I guess the modifier key needs to move.

What is the best approach here? 
Are there other British keyboard users, who can advise me on what they have done and how to do it effectively?

Comment: does the right alt key not work as alt-gr?

Comment: Nope they have equal functionality on Mac, unlike Linux. I could set it to just right Alt, but as a newbie to emacs I'm unsure how to setup Key bindings in a user based conf. The docs are not very helpful on this either.

Comment: If I added it to the dotspacemacs file then it will be overwritten on every update -- from what I can gather.

Comment: You must define the key combination to produce a pound symbol in your `.emacs` file with `define-key` or `global-set-key` (the latter is a wrapper around the former) as described in the following answers: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/44793/42068 or https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/79663/42068