# How can I use additional modifiers with terminal Emacs on MacOS?

Tags: key-bindings, osx, terminal-emacs, modifier-key

I currently have

```lisp
(setq ns-function-modifier 'hyper)
```

and it works perfectly fine on my GUI Emacs on MacOS, but it becomes a problem in terminal emacs, where it doesn't recognize the key. I was wondering how to fix this or to have my own command prefix.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer in this link: [How to swap `super` and `meta` in terminal Emacs on macOS?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/how-to-swap-super-and-meta-in-terminal-emacs-on-macos;) it is from Emacs manual, paragraph 39 IIRC, check it.

Comment: I already knew about the `C-x @` behavior. I was looking for an easy way to use my `fn` key as `super` or `hyper` within the terminal.

Comment: A more detailed explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418756/is-it-possible-to-make-emacs-interpret-an-fn-key-as-a-modifier-key