# Complex Modifier Combinations for emacs -nw

Tags: terminal-emacs, keyboard

I'm giving up on these fancy modifier keys, like Hyper, as they are not usable on emacs -nw

What other modifier combinations can I use?

I have a programmable keyboard, the Moonlander, so I can make whatever combinations I want.

I know Control-Alt is transferable through emacs -nw and ssh, but what about other more weird combinations?

like Control-Alt-Shift, but that doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

[Comprehensive keyboard handling in terminals](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/keyboard-protocol/) provides a good overview of what is possibe / not possible in terminals.

If you know how to put [`kitty`](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/) in progressive mode, then you can have whatever modifier keys you want.

Btw,  `kitty` can be taught how to handle `super` keys on `Debian` and `Mac`.  See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/73379/31220

This is how you teach `kitty` about `C-M-S-a`

```lisp
(define-key input-decode-map
            (kbd "ESC [ 9 7 ; 8 u")
            (kbd "C-M-S-a"))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-S-a")
                (defun hello-world ()
                  (interactive)
                  (message "Hello World")))
```

The above snippet is a TLDR of a more elaborate snippet here https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/73389/31220.